# Xamarin forms Entry

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How i can find entry changed?

```
<Entry x:Name="one" Keyboard="Numeric" TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged" />
<Entry x:Name="two" Keyboard="Numeric" TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged" />
<Entry x:Name="tre" Keyboard="Numeric" TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged" />

private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //which entry's value has changed (x:Name)
}
```

is there any way to find out?

Comment: `sender` will be a reference to the element that fired the event

Comment: Of course, but I want to find out which Entry was changed. one or two or three

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Of course, but I want to find out which Entry was changed. one or two or three

You cannot access the x:Name property of a xaml element, because this is just a hint for the compiler to name the variable.

You can set the ClassId of your Entry so that you can retrieve it in the handler. Like this:

```
 <Entry
            x:Name="one"
            ClassId="entry1"
            Keyboard="Numeric"
            TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged" />
        <Entry
            x:Name="two"
            ClassId="entry2"
            Keyboard="Numeric"
            TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged" />
        <Entry
            x:Name="tre"
            ClassId="entry3"
            Keyboard="Numeric"
            TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged" />

 private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var entry = (Entry)sender;
        if(entry.ClassId==one.ClassId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you are in one entry");
        }
        else if(entry.ClassId==two.ClassId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you are in two entry");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you are in three entry");
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the sender!

```
private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //which entry's value has changed (x:Name)
    Entry theTextBox = (Entry)sender;
    Console.WriteLine(theTextBox.Name) + " changed the value");
}
```

Comment: I Couldn't see the (theTextBox) "Name" property

Comment: This was just a sample to cast the sender as Entry and do the comparison. I didn't test while writing this solution...